# Where is Current Apple Sandbox Documentation

Tags: macos, documentation, sandbox, appstore-sandbox

All the Apple documentation on sandboxing my Mac app that I can find is listed as no longer being maintained. More exactly, it is the About App Sandbox introduction to the App Sandboxing Design Guide that is so listed.  Presumably, this applies to the rest of the guide.

Is there current documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I think [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html) and [this other](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4) too should be the current ones that you are searching for

Comment: Thanks.  They are listed as no longer maintained.